# How can i Extract individual values from a two Ordered Dictionaries combined?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to return two Ordered Dictionaries, the return statement is as follow:

```
return self.objects, self.disappeared
```

They are initialized as:

```
self.objects = OrderedDict()
self.disappeared = OrderedDict()
```

After returning, the combined version was printed out as:

```
(OrderedDict([(0, array([260, 181]))]), OrderedDict([(0, 0)]))
```

I am currently extracting it as:

```
for (objectID, centroid) in objects.items():
```

However, this is only possible when I'm returning just `self.objects` or `self.disappeared`, not both.

How would I be able to extract values with two returning Dictionaries?

Comment: You don't have "combined" dict, you have a tuple of OrderedDict's.  If you then need to combine the tuple into one then call update() method of first with second dict as parameter .. or create a new dict with `**´ operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your issue is in handling the returned tuples.
Check out "**2) Using Tuple**" from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-41-multiple-return-values-in-python/.

Here is an example code snippet using the pieces that you provided.

```
from typing import OrderedDict

class Thing:
    def __init__(self):
        # "They are initialized as: "
        self.objects = OrderedDict(objectID=1, centroid=[2,3])
        self.disappeared = OrderedDict(unknown=(4,5))

    def do_thing(self):
        # "I am trying to return two Ordered Dictionaries, the return statement is as follow: "
        return self.objects, self.disappeared

# "After returning, the combined version was printed out as: "
results = Thing().do_thing()
print(results)

# "How would I be able to extract values with two returning Dictionaries? "
objects, disappeared = results

for (objectID, centroid) in objects.items():
    print(f'{objectID}, {centroid}')

for item in disappeared.items():
    print(item)
```

In `do_thing()` we are returning a **tuple** of `(self.objects, self.disappeared)`.

We can unpack this tuple (extract each item) like so:

```
objects, disappeared = results
```

More info about unpacking tuples: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unpacking-a-tuple-in-python/

Then you will be able to be able to use the code as written:

```
for (objectID, centroid) in objects.items():
    print(f'{objectID}, {centroid}')
```